# 2 belongsTo associations on the same table in cakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have an entity where I would like to have 2 belongsTo associations and not 1 belongsToMany associations.

So I would like to link Orders to Agpoitexts through agpoitext_id but I would also link Orders to AgpoiTexts with `ref_id`, to produce the following sql query:

Thanks to the example in the doc about hasMany association below:

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('Comments', [
            'className' => 'Comments',
            'conditions' => ['approved' => true]
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('UnapprovedComments', [
            'className' => 'Comments',
            'conditions' => ['approved' => false],
            'propertyName' => 'unapproved_comments'
        ]);
   }
}
```

I though I could successfully get it by:

```
class OrdersTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {

        $this->belongsTo('Agpoitexts', [
            'dependent' => true,
            'foreignKey' => 'agpoitext_id',
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('References', [
            'className' => 'Agpoitexts',
            'foreignKey' => 'ref_id',
        ]);

    }
}
```

But I get an error as Cake generates the following query and looks for `references` table :

```
... LEFT JOIN agpoitexts References ON References.id = (Orders.ref_id) LEFT JOIN agpoitexts Agpoitexts ON Agpoitexts.id = (Orders.agpoitext_id) ...
```

Is it possible to get what I want?

Regards,

**EDIT :** the error I get:

`Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'References ON References.id = (Orders.ref_id) LEFT JOIN agpoitexts Agpoitexts ON' at line 1`

What I want is `Agpoitexts.id = Orders.ref_id`.

Comment: It's not joining the `references` table. `References` is an alias of `agpoitexts`. Both joins are on `agpoitexts`. Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: @InigoFlores it's exactly what I want but I think I need an alias because I cannot declare to belongsTo to the same table because I would have to write `contain(['Agpoitexts', 'Agpoitexts'])`. So I'm looking for a syntax which allows me to write `contain(['Agpoitexts', 'Reference'])` to access to `agpoitexts` table through `Agpoitexts` by `agpoitext_id` and through `References` by ref_I'd. I edit my post to display the error I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name chosen for your table alias is what is causing the error message you are getting.

`References`is a reserved work in MySQL. Try choosing a different word that is not in the list of reserverd words.

See [9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)